# How can I modify vsftpd.conf in macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, unix, ftp

I've installed `vsftpd` via Homebrew, and I found that the `vsftpd.conf` file should be modified in order to set write_enable=yes and put file.

I googled and tried to find `vsftpd.conf` in my MacBook, but I couldn't find where it is.

Generally, in Unix and Linux, `vsftpd.conf` exists in `/etc/vsftpd/` but I cannot locate that directory in my computer.

Could you tell me where `vsftpd.conf` is in macOS?

Answer (score 2):

You should have gotten the following output while installing `vsftpd`:

```
To use chroot, vsftpd requires root privileges, so you will need to run
  sudo vsftpd.
You should be certain that you trust any software you grant root privileges.

The vsftpd.conf file must be owned by root or vsftpd will refuse to start:
  sudo chown root /usr/local/etc/vsftpd.conf

To have launchd start vsftpd now and restart at startup:
  sudo brew services start vsftpd
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  sudo vsftpd
```

So your `vsftpd.conf` file is in `/usr/local/etc`.

Comment: thanks! i didn't read output you wrote .... 
I found vsftpd.conf in there